# Laplace equation in simple domains

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

I have a problem understanding when and how to use the bessel function, I'm completely confused what should I do with boundary conditions. Could you please advise me and if it's possible give me examples or exercises where i should use Bessel function and where i should not

> $\Delta u=0$ on a circle with radius $r\in[1,2]$, boundary conditions are 
> $u|_{r=1}=sin(2\phi)sin(3\phi),$ 
> $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}|_{r=2} = cos(2\phi)cos(3\phi)$

I'm trying $u(r,\phi) = R(r)\cdot \Phi(\phi)$ 
$r^2\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{R'}{R}+\frac{\Phi''}{\Phi}=0,$ 
$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\Phi''+\lambda_1\Phi=0\\
\Phi(0)=\Phi(2\pi) =0\\
\end{aligned}
\right.$, then 
$\Phi_0=1,$ 
$\Phi_{k,1}=cos\sqrt\lambda_1\phi$ 
$\Phi_{k,2}=sin\sqrt\lambda_1\phi$ 
$r^2R''+rR'+R(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)=0,$ $t = \alpha r$ 
$R_r'= \alpha R_t'$ 
$R_r''= \alpha^2 R_t''$ 
$\alpha = \sqrt\lambda$ 
$R(t)=J_k(\sqrt\lambda r)$ 
$J_k(\sqrt\lambda R) =0, $ $\mu_n^k$ - the n-th positive root $J_k$ 
$\lambda_{k,n} = (\frac{\mu_n^k}{R})^2$ 
$R_{k,n}=J_k(\frac{\mu_n^k}{R}r)$ 
$u=\sum\limits_{\forall k,n}\Phi_{k,n}R_{k,n}$

Comment: You should "use" [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) when you have to solve Bessel's differential equation, 
$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+(\alpha^2-x^2)y=0.$$
However, that equation do not show up when one solves the problem you presented. (You can find the solution of Laplace's equation in polar coordinates [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169257/boundary-value-problem-laplaces-equation-in-polar-coordinates?rq=1).)